how break or leak information from a recurrence equation?
i have this equation which is cracking my head.
$k_i = (((tab[i_{i-3}]>>8  \oplus tab[i_{i-2}])>>8 \oplus tab[i_{i_1}])>>8 \oplus tab[i])$
And i have discovered that:
$tab[x_i] \oplus crcpoly = tab[x_i \oplus 0x80]$
but what i can't figure out is what is the relationship between $pk$ and $k_i$ where $pk$ is:
$pk = (((crcpoly>>8 \oplus crcpoly)>>8 \oplus crcpoly)>>8 \oplus crcpoly)$
And how i can use $pk$ or $crcpoly$ to solve some parts of $k_i$ given that $k_i$ itself is known.
$pk \oplus k_i =$?
I know that first byte of the result of $pk \oplus k_i$  is the first byte $k_i \oplus tab[0x80]$ but i couldn't figure out the meaning of the rest of the bytes.
Note: This is based on the CRC32.
Please help, i need to understand what i have gotten myself into.
